# How do bit values relate to floating points in terms of the exp and frac? Assume I understand how "s" works.

Tags: floating-point

So, I'm still going through Floating Points in Computer Systems a Programmer's perspective, and I have gotten further in Floating points.

Now, this is a queer set I find: 
0 0001 000 = The Smallest Norm which ==  0.015625 
0 0110 110 = The Number One Which == 0.875

Now, I understand that first 0 is just s, and the next 4 zeroes are exp and the three after that are frac, what I do NOT understand completely is the math behind them.

For example, with what I have learned about binary representation so far in the number 0 0110 110 should rightly be 53/256, but that's not even close to the M representation in the book which is: 14/8.

Then we have the Smallest Normal which is 9/8. I know how s, exp, and frac are represented, but I'm still not entirely clear on where these binary representations come from.

Comment: Your question refers to some unspecified 8-bit format. This is not a standard format, so other people are not familiar with it. When asking questions about non-standard formats, you should provide all the information that specifies the format.

Comment: Re “0 0110 110 should rightly be 53/256”. If the sequence of bits “00110110” is interpreted as a binary numeral, it is 54, not 53. This is not a matter of “rightly” versus “wrongly”; by itself, a sequence of bits is just a sequence of bits with no meaning. We often choose to use a sequence of bits to convey a binary numeral, but we also use them to convey characters, arbitrary codes, floating-point data, or whatnot. Some of your problems interpreting floating-point data seem to arise from incorrectly assuming sequences of bits are necessarily binary numerals.

Comment: Besides NaNs and Denormalized numbers, do sequences not become binary numerals?

Comment: A sequence is merely a list. A sequence of bits is a list of bits. If sometime in January, I look out my window each day for three days and write 1 if there is snow on the ground and 0 if there is not, I might get a list of bits 1 0 1. That does not mean five. It is not a binary numeral. It is a list of bits. This particular list is a record of snow observations. It does not mean a number. There is no five snow or five things. It is just bits. We **can** use a list of bits as a binary numeral, but a list of bits can also mean many other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question refers to some unspecified 8-bit floating-point format. I will answer assuming this format follows the pattern set by IEEE-754 binary floating-point formats.

The question indicates the first bit is the sign bit, the next four bits are for the exponent, and the last three are for the significand (fraction portion). Let *s* be the sign bit, *e* be the exponent bits, and *f* be the significand bits.

In IEEE-754 formats, the exponent bits are key to what is represented:

- If all bits in *e* are zero, the object represents zero or a subnormal number.
- If all bits in *e* are one, the object represents infinity or a NaN.
- Otherwise, the object represents a normal number.

Once that classification is decided, here is how the value is determined for normal numbers:

- If *s* is 0 or 1, the sign *S* is +1 or −1, respectively.
- The bits of *e* are interpreted as a binary numeral, and some bias is subtracted to produce an exponent *E*. The bias is half the maximum possible value of *e*, rounded down. For example, with four bits, the maximum value would be 1111<sub>2</sub>, which is 15<sub>10</sub>. Half of that, rounded down, is 7. So if the bits of *e* are “0110”, the exponent *E* is 6−7 = −1.
- A significand *F* is computed by forming a binary numeral starting with “1.” and followed by the bits of *f*. *F* is the value of this binary numeral. For example, if *f* is “110”, the numeral “1.110” is formed, and this has value 1 + ½ + ¼ = 1.75.
- The value represented by the bits of the object is *S* • 2<sup>*E*</sup> • *F*. So, for the bits “0 0110 110”, the value represented is +1 • 2<sup>−1</sup> • 1.75 = .875.

From the above, we can see the smallest positive normal number has sign bit “0”, exponent bits “0001” (it cannot be “0000”, because that is subnormal), and significand bits “000”). Then the represented value has sign +1, exponent 1−7 = −6, and significand 1, so the value is +1 • 2<sup>−6</sup> • 1 = 2<sup>−6</sup> = .015625.

Here is how the value is determined for subnormal numbers:

- If *s* is 0 or 1, the sign *S* is +1 or −1, respectively.
- The exponent *E* has the same value as for the smallest normal number. This is 1 minus the bias, so *E* = 1−7 = −6.
- A significand *F* is computed by forming a binary numeral starting with “0.” and followed by the bits of *f*. *F* is the value of this binary numeral.
- The value represented by the bits of the object is *S* • 2<sup>*E*</sup> • *F*.

For infinity and NaNs:

- If *f* is all zeros, the value is infinity. It is +infinity or −infinity according to the bit *s*.
- Otherwise, the object is a NaN. IEEE-754 is not strict, but, if the first bit of *f* is 1, the object should represent a quiet NaN. Otherwise, it should represent a signaling NaN. Otherwise, the bits of *f* are available for diagnostic or other uses.